# make the Nav bar text Centered

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

How do i make the text centered within my nav and ensure that it stays that way from all resolutions (1920x1080 it is left, 1420, its centered)

I also realise that alot of this code is useless and not working, but at this point i just want to get it fixed before i decide on tidying it up.

```
        /* Navigation Menu */
  .main-navigation {
    text-align:center;
        margin-top: 24px;
        margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
        text-align: center;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:958px;
        margin-top: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .main-navigation li {
    text-align:center;
        margin-top: 24px;
        margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
        font-size: 16px;
        color:#fff;
        font-size: 0.857142857rem;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
    }
    .main-navigation a {
        color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .main-navigation a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        height:37px;

    }
    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
    .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    text-align:center;
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on,
    .menu-toggle {
    text-align:center;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .nav-menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:05px;
    padding-left:20%;
    left:0px;
    top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 350px;
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
      display: inline-block;
    background:none;
```

http://yesyesdev.info/talks
DEV server is having problems, but if you get the error 500, just refresh a couple of times.

Comment: You have provided a crashed link :) please correct that

Comment: This might be helpful. http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do have indeed way too many useless code.
Remove the following:

line 767 
    .main-navigation {
<strike>display: inline-block;</strike> 
}

line 805 .nav-menu { 
<strike>position: fixed;</strike>  
<strike>float: left;</strike>   
}